# Encrypt Connection String in Web.Config Fails

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config

I would like to encrypt the connection string of my web.config. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Configuration_File.aspx) I have found a nice example on how to do this. I implemented this and on my development machine this runs find.
However if I upload it to the provider, it does not work with the following error:

*[SecurityException: Request failed.]
   System.Configuration.DpapiProtectedConfigurationProvider.Encrypt(XmlNode node)*

In [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/shahed/archive/2007/07/15/113954.aspx) blog I have read, that this is because of the web probably runs in medium trust and therefore `WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration` can not be used. Instead of this, `WebConfigurationManager.GetSection` should be used. However, if I get the section as proposed, the call to `ProtectSection` fails with the following error message:

*System.InvalidOperationException: This operation does not apply at runtime*

Can anyone lead me to a solution, how I can encode (and decode) the connection string in the web.config file (at runtime)?

**Update**
Not a real answer to the question, but the hoster gave full trust to the web and now, all worked fine. I leave the quesion open, maybe someone posts a solution to the original question and helps with this people having the same problem but not getting full trust.

Answer (score 1):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

```
static void ToggleWebEncrypt()
{
    // Open the Web.config file.
    Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.
        OpenWebConfiguration("~");

    // Get the connectionStrings section.
    ConnectionStringsSection section =
        config.GetSection("connectionStrings")
        as ConnectionStringsSection;

    // Toggle encryption.
    if (section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
    {
        section.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
    }
    else
    {
        section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(
            "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
    }

    // Save changes to the Web.config file.
    config.Save();
}
```

**UPDATE**

Also, ensure that your service account has write permissions to the Web.config. Also, be aware that granting write permissions to your service account on the Web.config increases somewhat the security footprint of your application. Only do so if you understand and accept the risks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However is the line Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");  the source of the exception, IIS does not execute it and throws a SecurityException!

Comment: @HCL: Does your service account have write permissions on the web.config file?

Comment: @kbrimington: Yes, the configuration tool of the hoster allows me to grant permission on a directory base and I gave testwise IUSR read/write permissions on the root (also of the virtual directory).

Comment: @kbrimington: It seems really like the Shahed Khan writes in his post, the description of the error is as follows: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file

Comment: @HCL: Am I correct that it is still not working? If so, note that unless you are using impersonation, granting IUSR permissions does not solve the problem. It is the *service* account, not the *user* account that needs write permissions. You can use `Environment.UserName` to ferret out the name of the account, if you don't know it already.

Comment: @kbrimington: Event Environment.UserName is not available, if I call it, I get also a security exception. Therefore, I don't know under which account the service acts: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.EnvironmentPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed

Comment: @HCL. Huh. Having never used 3-rd party hosting, it never occurred to me that special permissions were required to determine the service account name. If you don't have access to the name via IIS or some other means, consider giving your service provider a call and explain the situation. I'm still ready to wager that once write permissions are granted to the right account, you'll be good to go.

Comment: @HCL. Some hosts will use the group IIS_WPG to represent the worker process group. It may be a stretch, but you could try granting permissions to that group, if it exists.

Comment: @kbrimington: I only can grant permissions to IUSR, it's the only security option in the configuration applet. Probably it's only called IUSR because in ancient times it was IUSR :)

Comment: @kbrimington: +1 Thanks for your time. I will give them tomorrow a call.